# Problems with Alamofire response handler

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

For my project I want to parse an Alamofire JSON response and save it in Realm. I already tested this by fetching the JSON from a Mock-API and it worked fine, but when I'm trying to incorporate my Code into my AM-response handling I'm getting this error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(AFDataResponse) throws -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Any, AFError>) throws -> ()') to non-throwing function type '(AFDataResponse) -> Void' (aka '(DataResponse<Any, AFError>) -> ()')

The Code for the response looks like this:

```
 .responseJSON { response in //this is where I'm getting the error
                print(response)
        self.books = [Books]()
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject] {
        
        if let booksFromJson = json["books"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
            for bookFromJson in booksFromJson {
                let book = Books()
                if let title = bookFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = bookFromJson["author"] as? String, let imageLink = bookFromJson["imageLink"] as? String {
                    
                    book.author = author
                    book.title = title
                    book.imageLink = imageLink
                    
                }
                self.books?.append(book)
   
                                 }
```

This is my AM-Request as a whole:

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
 if let image:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
     self.myImage = image
     
     
     AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(self.myImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
     
     }, to: "https://booknerdvirtualreadinglist.herokuapp.com/getbook" , headers: nil )
     .uploadProgress { progress in
                 print(progress)
             }
     .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
        self.books = [Books]()
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject] {
        
        if let booksFromJson = json["books"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]{
            for bookFromJson in booksFromJson {
                let book = Books()
                if let title = bookFromJson["title"] as? String, let author = bookFromJson["author"] as? String, let imageLink = bookFromJson["imageLink"] as? String {
                    
                    book.author = author
                    book.title = title
                    book.imageLink = imageLink
                    
                }
                self.books?.append(book)
   
                                 }
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why duplicate? Also, if I remember well, it should be: `switch response { case .failure(let afError): print(error); case .success(let res): if let json = res as? [String: AnyObject] { //do the rest as your code }}`

Comment: Unrelated but a JSON value is never reference type (`AnyObject`), it's `Any`. And `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift particularly if you assign the result to an **im**mutable constant.

Comment: Please post your solution **in an answer**, not in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not catching the error correctly because your "try catch" only has a do block.

This is how you can properly handle an error in Swift:

```
do {
    // some throwing code
} catch {
    print("Failed with error \(error)")
}
```

The catch-part is missing.